# Are Brahmins allowed to cross the sea (means foreign countries like America,Australia,etc)?

Tags: scripture, brahmins

I have heard many of people refusing to cross sea saying that It is wrong.So please I want a Clarification about this and also If any references from Scriptures will be nice and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Few related or duplicate Q: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=samudrolanghana